# Drawing on the screen, outside the shell using java swt?

Tags: java, drawing, swt

I saw an eclipse editor (e4 css spy) which draws a tiny frame around open shells. 
It draws the frame on the screen, outisde the shells. 
The Border stays on the screen, when the shells are moved away.

What API should I use to draw directly on the screen, without a window?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It creates a new non-rectangular shell:

```
Shell selectedShell = ... get the shell to highlight

Rectangle bounds = .. get bounds relative to absolute display

// create the highlight; want it to appear on top

Shell highlight = new Shell(selectedShell, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.NO_FOCUS | SWT.ON_TOP);

highlight.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

Region highlightRegion = new Region();
highlightRegion.add(0, 0, 1, bounds.height + 2);
highlightRegion.add(0, 0, bounds.width + 2, 1);
highlightRegion.add(bounds.width + 1, 0, 1, bounds.height + 2);
highlightRegion.add(0, bounds.height + 1, bounds.width + 2, 1);

highlight.setRegion(highlightRegion);

highlight.setBounds(bounds.x - 1, bounds.y - 1, bounds.width + 2, bounds.height + 2);

highlight.setEnabled(false);

highlight.setVisible(true); // not open(): setVisible() prevents taking focus
```

Taken from `org.eclipse.e4.tools.css.spy.CssSpyDialog` and reformatted for clarity.